# axiosでgetしたデータについて

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

#### 前提・実現したいこと

以下のコードで22行目の　console.log(getData());　から11行目のdataを出力したいと思っていますが、以下のようにエラーメッセージが出ます。

改善方法を教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
data is not defined
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```js
let axios = require("axios");

let cityNumber = "130010";
let url = "https://weather.tsukumijima.net/api/forecast?city=" + cityNumber;

function getData() {
    axios
        .get(url)

    .then((response) => {
            let data =
                response.data.forecasts[0].date +
                "の天気は" +
                response.data.forecasts[0].detail.weather +
                "\n"; 
            return data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("ERROR", err);
        });
}
console.log(getData());
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Node.js v14.17.5.

Comment: 本当に、このコードを実行した結果としてこのエラーメッセージが出ていますか？（実際は異なる問題が起きてませんか？）

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。node.jsで実行した場合"undefind"と帰ってきました。詳しく教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: `Promise` 使ってるようなので, 処理が完了していないのでは？
何らかの問題が発生しているのなら, 正しく状況記さないと, (その情報元にするので) 間違った答えに進むか, 混乱を招きます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getData()`が何も返していないことが原因です。

次のように書き換えてみてください。

```
function getData() {
    return axios // <-- !!
        .get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            let data =
               response.data.forecasts[0].date +
                "の天気は" +
               response.data.forecasts[0].detail.weather +
                "\n";
            return data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("ERROR", err);
        });
}

getData().then(data => console.log(data));
```

ここで`getData()`が返すのはPromiseなので、呼び出し側もそれを処理するようなコードになっています。

Comment: うまくいきました！ありがとうございます。